Passing an object/map as named arguments/properties to a Flutter Widget
As I extend Flutter widgets, I'd like a way to pass any properties to the original widget without having to specify them all on my widget three times beforehand, or modifying it every time I want to use a new property, like this:
class DataTableFromMap extends StatelessWidget {
  final List tableData;
  final int? sortColumnIndex;
  final bool sortAscending;
  final ValueSetter<bool?>? onSelectAll;
  final Decoration? decoration;
  final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? dataRowColor;
  // And every other prop...

  const DataTableFromMap({
    super.key,
    required this.tableData,
    this.sortColumnIndex,
    this.sortAscending,
    this.onSelectAll,
    this.decoration,
    this.dataRowColor,
  // And every other prop...
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: _createColumns(tableData.first),
      rows: _createRows(tableData)),
      sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
      sortAscending: sortAscending,
      onSelectAll: onSelectAll,
      decoration: decoration,
      dataRowColor: dataRowColor,
      // And every other prop...
    )
  }

Instead I could pass a map argument with any props I need (say, tableProps), and then just call the desired widget with something like:
DataTable({
    columns: _createColumns(tableData.first),
    rows: _createRows(tableData)),
    ...tableProps
});

I tried this, but the results were not entirely satisfactory:
class DataTableFromMap extends StatelessWidget {
  final List tableData;
  final Map tableProps;

  const DataTableFromMap({
    super.key,
    required this.tableData,
    this.tableProps = const {},
  });

Destructuring doesn't work like in JS/React.  tableProps has to be converted to symbols, and then feed through Function.apply:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => createDataTableFromMap(tableData);

  DataTable createDataTableFromMap(tableData) {
    // Properties must be symbols, "symbolize" props
    final props = symbolizeKeys({
      "columns": _createColumns(tableData.first),
      "rows": _createRows(tableData),
      ...tableProps,
    });
    print(props);

    return Function.apply(DataTable.new, [], props);
  }

Then I just call my widget with any props I need:
  final tableProps = {
    "headingRowColor": MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
      return const Color.fromRGBO(200, 100, 50, 1);
    }),
    "horizontalMargin": 48.0
  };

  // ...

    DataTableFromMap(tableData: testData, tableProps: tableProps),

It works, as can be seen on this DartPad and the full code below, but with several drawbacks: prop names end up as quoted strings, so I lose auto-completion and name and type checks, and someone mentioned the Function.apply(DataTable.new) trick could generate bloated JS.
I'm hoping there's a better way to do this.  The devs state that you should almost always prefer a widget over helper methods, and should subclass Stateless/fullWidget instead of the actual widget class, and that's what I tried, but perhaps this could be better achieved breaking those pointers?  Thanks for any advice.
Full code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(BundleOptParamsTest());
}

class BundleOptParamsTest extends StatelessWidget {
  BundleOptParamsTest({super.key});

  final testData = [
    {'name': 'Babes', 'number': 123},
    {'name': 'Smokes', 'number': 7890},
    {'name': 'Rocks', 'number': 09871234}
  ];

  final tableProps = {
    "headingRowColor": MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
      return const Color.fromRGBO(200, 100, 50, 1);
    }),
    "horizontalMargin": 48.0
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bundling Optional Parameters to Class Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: DataTableFromMap(tableData: testData, tableProps: tableProps),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class DataTableFromMap extends StatelessWidget {
  final List tableData;
  final Map tableProps;

  const DataTableFromMap({
    super.key,
    required this.tableData,
    this.tableProps = const {},
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => createDataTableFromMap(tableData);

  DataTable createDataTableFromMap(tableData) {
    // Properties must be symbols, "symbolize" props
    final props = symbolizeKeys({
      "columns": _createColumns(tableData.first),
      "rows": _createRows(tableData),
      ...tableProps,
    });
    print(props);

    return Function.apply(DataTable.new, [], props);
  }

  List<DataColumn> _createColumns(sampleRow) {
    return [
      for (final e in sampleRow.entries)
        DataColumn(label: Text(e.key.toString()), numeric: (e.value is num))
    ];
  }

  List<DataRow> _createRows(tableData) {
    return [
      for (final row in tableData)
        DataRow(cells: [
          for (final v in row.values)
            DataCell(Text(v is String ? v : v.toString().asThousands))
        ])
    ];
  }
}

/// Return a numeric string formatted in thousands.
/// Example: -123456.toString().asThousands() returns -123,456
extension on String {
  String get asThousands {
    final numberDigits = List.from(split(''));
    int index = numberDigits.length - 3;
    while (index > 0) {
      numberDigits.insert(index, ',');
      index -= 3;
    }
    return numberDigits.join();
  }
}

// Transform the keys of `map` into Symbols so it can be used as named arguments with `Function.apply()`
Map<Symbol, dynamic> symbolizeKeys(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(Symbol(k), v));
}


Play on DartPad.

maybe this experimental macros language feature is what you are looking for?

I know you don't like to define all properties that you're just gonna pass, but I still think it's probably the best way. It's done in numerous places within widgets that come with Flutter itself. If there was a better way than they probably would have done that themselves as well. But I guess it's subjective also

Macros looks neat @pskink.  Automated generation of boilerplate would do the trick.  Experimental tho, but I'll keep on eye of them (if I don't end up just switching to ClojureDart).

There's a big Flutter ecosystem beyond the devs @Ivo, and I've only skimmed the surface.  Remi Rousselet alone has made it much more dev friendly with Riverpod and React-inspired flutter_hooks. SrPanda's demo below looks promising, if only I can manage to turn his black magickz into a general solution.  Which made me realise, I should also check Remi's provider, a InheritedWidget wrapper!

Flutter already has a way to do that but not in the exact way you think. The widgets that the framework uses/provides rely on the use of the InheritedWidget, which is a widget that it's soul purpose is to provide values to descending widgets, this approach makes it quite easy to not depend on singletons or static values to configure large parts of the code.
I should note that most InheritedWidget implementations are treated as if they where singletons, this makes them simpler to use and override.
For the example you have, flutter already has what you want, the ThemeData contains those exact parameters in it's instance of DataTableThemeData. In this example I chose to use sliders to adjust the parameters to show that unless you look into the implementation you wont know for sure what the widgets are doing, here you might asume that the ThemeData just feeds into a InheritedTheme but it's not quite like that, that InheritedWidget also feeds into a AnimatedTheme which is what causes that delay.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  AppState createState() => AppState();
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  static const sample_data = [
    {'name': 'Babes', 'number': 123},
    {'name': 'Smokes', 'number': 7890},
    {'name': 'Rocks', 'number': 09871234}
  ];

  ThemeData theme = ThemeData.from(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  );

  Widget _build_table(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      rows: sample_data
          .map(
            (point) => DataRow(
              cells: point.values
                  .map(
                    (value) => DataCell(Text(value.toString())),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      columns: sample_data.first.keys
          .map(
            (key) => DataColumn(
              label: Text(key),
              numeric: sample_data.first[key] is num,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }

  double _color = 0;
  double _horizontal_margin = 0;

  final _options_key = GlobalKey();

  Widget _build_options(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      key: _options_key,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Text('Margin'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: Slider(
                value: _horizontal_margin,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _horizontal_margin = value;
                  theme = theme.copyWith(
                    dataTableTheme: theme.dataTableTheme.copyWith(
                      horizontalMargin: _horizontal_margin * 100,
                    ),
                  );
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Text('Color'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: Slider(
                value: _color,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _color = value;
                  theme = theme.copyWith(
                    dataTableTheme: theme.dataTableTheme.copyWith(
                      // headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith( // Old way
                      headingRowColor: WidgetStateColor.resolveWith(
                        (states) =>
                            Color((0xFFFFFF * _color).toInt() | 0xFF000000),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: theme,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500),
              child: _build_table(context),
            ),
            _build_options(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

